# sidebar sub-menu toggle in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two sidebar menu `Income` and `Expense`. Under each menu there are some sub-menus. I want that whenever I click on `Income` menu the sub-menus will show under it. But whenever click on `Expense` the other sub-menus will show under it and `Income` menu's sub-menu become hide.
But in my website those are overlap each other.

Here is the html

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul id="sidebarnav">
            <li>
                <a href="/title" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-clock-o m-r-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>Title</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item-one">
                <a href="" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-user m-r-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="menu-title">Income</span></a>

                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/income" data-i18n="nav.cards.card_bootstrap" class="menu-item">
                            Add Income
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/dailyIncomeReport" data-i18n="nav.cards.card_bootstrap" class="menu-item">
                            Daily Report
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item-two">
                <a href="" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-table m-r-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="menu-title">Expense</span></a></a>

                <ul class="menu-content-two">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/expense" data-i18n="nav.cards.card_bootstrap" class="menu-item">
                            Add Expense
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/dailyExpenseReport" data-i18n="nav.cards.card_bootstrap" class="menu-item">
                            Daily Report
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>                        
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function($) {

            //$('.menu-content').hide();

            $(".nav-item-one:has(ul)").click(function(){
                ('.menu-content-two').hide();
                $("ul",this).toggle('slow');
            });


            //$('.menu-content-two').hide();

            $(".nav-item-two:has(ul)").click(function(){
                $('.menu-content').hide();
                $("ul",this).toggle('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: "Overlap" without showing some CSS...

Comment: Give me sample of code plz

Comment: Wow, don't bind to raw html elements, you are asking for any html changes to break your javascript.  Take a moment and read [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: Arafat please attach full html i will fix it

Comment: @AbidNawaz ... I have updated the code. Here is the body part of HTML

Comment: this is what you are looking for ?  https://fiddle.jshell.net/marwat/3cx5Lom3/

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(".nav-item-one").click(function(){

                $('.menu-content-two').hide();
                $("ul",this).toggle('slow');
            });


            //$('.menu-content-two').hide();

            $(".nav-item-two").click(function(){
                $('.menu-content').hide();
                $("ul",this).toggle('slow');
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul id="sidebarnav">
            <li>
                <a href="/title" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-clock-o m-r-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>Title</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item-one">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-user m-r-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="menu-title">Income</span></a>

                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/income" data-i18n="nav.cards.card_bootstrap" class="menu-item">
                            Add Income
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/dailyIncomeReport" data-i18n="nav.cards.card_bootstrap" class="menu-item">
                            Daily Report
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item-two">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-table m-r-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="menu-title">Expense</span></a>

                <ul class="menu-content-two">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/expense" data-i18n="nav.cards.card_bootstrap" class="menu-item">
                            Add Expense
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/dailyExpenseReport" data-i18n="nav.cards.card_bootstrap" class="menu-item">
                            Daily Report
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>                        
        </ul>
    </nav>
```